# Error resolving type specified in JSON .$type'.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not load assembly 'LivePersonConnector'

Tags: c#, json, azure, botframework, azure-cosmosdb

I'm integrating one off the handoff sample (Live person Proxy Assistant) from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples) to my bot framework solution. Im using azure cosmos db for storing the conversation states. And the Code works as expected. I have also integrated my bot with Microsoft teams. Recently I had publish my old solution (which was not integrated with live person sample). & the my bot works as expected in webchat, whereas in Microsoft teams it is not responding and when I check the logs in azure console It shows the following

**LoggingMiddlewareCosmosDb.cs-OnTurnAsync, Message : Error resolving type specified in JSON 'LivePersonConnector.EscalationsConversationData, LivePersonConnector'. Path 'EscalationsConversationData.$type'.Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Could not load assembly 'LivePersonConnector'.
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultSerializationBinder.GetTypeFromTypeNameKey(StructMultiKey2 typeNameKey) at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func2 valueFactory) at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ThreadSafeStore2.Get(TKey key)**

Since I have published the solution which is not integrated with live person solution It is strange that it asks for this particular assembly. Tried clearing cache for MS teams but it doesn't work.

If i publish my solution(which is not integrated with liveperson sample) after publishing the liveperson sample integrated bot Im seeing this error - **#ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_TO_SITE_FOLDER.)**

But even after deleting the dll and publishing the app to azure I;m still facing the same error for Microsoft teams.